# Keystonejs 5: Automatically populate parent in create admin

Tags: javascript, graphql, keystonejs

I'm trying to make it so that when I hit the "+" to add a child object on the edit form in the keystonejs 5 admin UI, it automatically sets the parent in this form.

I am sure it has something to do with "defaultValue", but I'm not sure what to pass to the default value.

Ideas?

[image: screen shot of keystone js admin ui showing where the parent should be populated in the child form]